# flutter emulate shell window with xterm

Tags: flutter

I am making an ssh function in my project. (with https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/ssh), right now session is connected with xterm, cmd can be expected, and the result from the ssh server is displayed in a Text widget, which will have the string like '[0m ... [0m', if I print the result into the console(print(result)), it will display correctly with the color specified, so how can I emulate a shell window which displays the result correctly in my app?

[The output of the app now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeEoC.jpg)

[Output in console which I want to emulate in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7YZv.jpg)

[another example of cmd 'top' in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soj4B.jpg)

[output in console that i want to realize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rnoM.jpg)

Comment: Is this the line of code that people see? `"${f["filename"]} ${f["isDirectory"]} ${f["modificationDate"]} ${f["lastAccess"]} ${f["fileSize"]} ${f["ownerUserID"]} ${f["ownerGroupID"]} ${f["permissions"]} ${f["flags"]}");` or is it the `_result` label?

Comment: do you mean the result? i think it is returned as string including '[0m...' in program

Answer (score 0):

Well, the weird `[0` you see are ANSI escape codes. These codes tell the terminal that a certain part of a string needs to get a color. You can find a list of colors here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors.

Then when you have that info, you will need some tool that can style parts of a `TextField`. In Flutter you can use the `RichText` class: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html. My suggestion is to do a find and replace on the text you are showing.

References:

[Display a few words in different colors in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50551933/display-a-few-words-in-different-colors-in-flutter)

[How to change the output color of echo in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux)

Comment: except the color,  it will need to transform all ansi codes(look the top example).