# How to change colors of text letters in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I want to change the color of letters in a text eg. I want to change the color of letter `H` to orange from text Hello and let the `ello` as it is in flutter. So how to change it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display a few words in different colors in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50551933/display-a-few-words-in-different-colors-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2):

If its static you can use [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

example

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'H',
    style: TextStyle(color:Colors.orange),
    children: const <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'ello', style: TextStyle()),
     
    ],
  ),
)
```

If its dynamic you might want to use plugins  eg [simple_rich_text](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_rich_text)

```
SimpleRichText(r'*_/this is all three*_/ (*{color:red}bold*, _{color:green}underlined_, and /{color:brown}italicized/). _{push:home;color:blue}clickable hyperlink to home screen_')
```

Comment: Thanks it really worked i added it and the colour changed

Answer (score 0):

```
Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              'H',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
            ),
            Text('ello')
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Row(
   children: [
   Text(
   'H',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
   ),
   Text('ELLO',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

RichText(
text: TextSpan(
text: 'H',
style: TextStyle(color:Colors.orange),
children: const [
TextSpan(text: 'ello', style: TextStyle()),
],
),
)

you can use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html